# How to convert a Ruby script into an executable

Tags: ruby, compilation, executable

I need to create an executable from my Ruby script that can be run using `./test <some-input>` on a remote testing server.

I cannot figure out how to convert a script into an executable on my Mac. I tried using rb2exe (and switching my version to 2.2.2 as directed) but that resulted in multiple errors.

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this?

Comment: If you just want to run it elsewhere, install Ruby there too and run the script as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a Ruby script with `ruby /pathtofile` at the command line. Why would you want to convert it to an EXE?

Ruby files are scripts. They need to be run by an interpreter. Executables are compiled programs.

Just call:

```
ruby your_program.rb
```

or start your program with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Make your file executable by running:

```
chmod +x your_program.rb
```

Run it with:

```
./your_program.rb some_paramameters
```

You could create a shell script to automatically run it as well.

Comment: Because on the remote server my solution will be tested on it will be run automatically using "./test <input>" which I cannot control. So using "ruby test.rb" isn't an option.

Comment: Why isnt that an option? You should be able to run it that way if it's configured correctly and depending on what it's exactly doing.

Comment: @MattHamer I added a little more that hopefully helps.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance but "./your_program.rb some_parameters" is also not going to work because "./your_program.rb ..." is not the same as "./your_program ..."

Comment: Or create a shell script called `test` and have it call `/usr/bin/env ruby your_program.rb`

Comment: Which is why I need to make this script into a true executable

Comment: Ahhh that just might do it

Comment: @MattHamer, you can call a program/script anything. `.rb` isn't magic, it's merely convention so we can glance at it and see what language it is. We piggyback on that when we open a file and an editor knows that type it is.

Comment: Make a file without extension. I did this for a game

`#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'pry'
require_relative '../lib/game.rb'

new_game = Game.new

new_game.play`